# Polymer and NodeJs/ Express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, polymer

I am using Polymer combined with a NodeJs/Express server which I am planning on hosting with Firebase functions.

My problem here is that besides the index.html none of the inner files can be found (404). With none of them I am revering to the first imports made inside my index file.(webcomponents-loader.js and the my-app.html)

I tried many different flavours. From absolute paths, with base tag and without and with a different directory structure.
I am clearly not an expert when it comes to node.js or express so I believe I am doing something fundamentally wrong.

**Update**
The links that can't be found have a different URL then the path that serves my index.html
404: http://localhost:5000/src/my-app.html 
index: http://localhost:5000/nodefire-96b46/us-central1/serve

**My directory:**

- fire_node

  - functions

    - node_modules
    - index.js
    - build

      - modern

        - bower_components
        - index.html
        - polymer.json
        - src

          - my-app

**My server file**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/build/modern'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => { 
  res.sendFile("index.html", {root: '.'});
});

app.listen(2000, () => {
  console.log('Server is listening on port 2000');
});
```

**My index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
    <title>My App</title>
    <base href="/modern/">
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
    <script>
      window.Polymer = { rootPath: '/' };
    </script>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="http://localhost:4000/fire_node/functions/build/modern/src/my-app.html">
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app></my-app>
    <noscript>
      Please enable JavaScript to view this website..
    </noscript>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: which file is giving 404? the `webcomponents-loader.js` or `my-app.html`?

Comment: Both, the webcomponents-loader.js and the my-app.html

Comment: Have you tried url's starting with `/` e.g. `src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"`?

Comment: Tried it but did not help.
I updated my answer with some more details

Comment: Instead of `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/build/modern'));` have you tried just `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/modern'));` ?